# Remove File In Spring Batch by using Tasklet but needs exit status from previous step

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have tasklet in spring batch which is used to remove the file that is present java temp folder. In my job, after running the main step, I have created one tasklet which will remove the file as a second step.

Requirements: I want to delete the file whether job runs with status completed or failed and wants to save the status of the main step.

Now, what happens If I used next in job configuration to pass tasklet then the file is not removed in case job was failed in the main step.

If I am using step flow to run the tasklet whether the main step is failed or completed then I am not able to use the status of the main step.

In Example, Below step1 is the main step and step3 is tasklet

```
    Tasklet: 
/**
     * Tasklet execution for remove file from local directory.
     *
     * @param contribution the contribution object
     * @param chunkContext       the chunck context object
     * @return the response status
     */
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(final StepContribution contribution, final ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        final String fileName = chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters().get("fullPathFileName").toString();
        log.info("Delete the file from local directory {} ", fileName);
        boolean deleted = Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(fileName));
        if (!deleted) {
            throw new UnexpectedJobExecutionException("Could not delete file " + fileName);
        }
        log.info("File removed successfully");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;

    }
Job Configuration With Step Flow:
public Job postalJob(ItemReader<PostalDto> postalReader) {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("postalJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1(postalReader)).on("*").to(step3()).end().listener(batchJobListener()).build();
    }

Job Configuration without step flow:
public Job postalJob(ItemReader<PostalDto> postalReader) {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("postalJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1(postalReader)).next(step3()).end().listener(batchJobListener()).build();
    }
Tasklet Configuration:
@Bean
    public Step step3() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("taskletStep").tasklet(fileDeletingTasklet()).build();
    }
```

In case you need more explanation on the same, please let me know.

Comment: `I am not able to use the status of the main step`: where do you need to use/access this status?

Comment: I already resolved this issue. Thanks for help

Comment: @VimitDhawan .. please share the answer to this , this will be help full to others , like Question-answer article